# LD_PRELOAD with MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

I was wondering: with LD_PRELOAD, I can overwrite, and intercept functions written in C/C++.
Is it possible, to intercept functions written in MySQL source code?

For example, I would like a log file, to contain all MySQL connections (for auditing reasons).
I would intercept the **mysql_real_connect()** C function is MySQL source, the following way:
    LD_PRELOAD=my_intercepting_connect.so mysql

Will it (in theory) work? Has anyone done this, or similar?

Answer (score 3):

With LD_PRELOAD you can intercept any symbol which an application pulls from a **shared** library. You can't intercept function calls which doesn't cross a binary border. So when your application is linked dynamically to mysql, you can intercept `mysql_real_connect` calls, when the application is linked statically, you are out of luck. Also you can't intercept calls within the mysql lib.